# Copy specific cell to a specific column

Tags: excel, vba

Cell E8 and E6 are dependent dropdown lists and they are working.

- If I select Tool in cell E8, than cell E6 gives a list of all the tools.
- If I select Equipment in cell E8, than cell E6 gives me all the equipment.

The range of this dependent dropdown list comes from columns K to M.

[image]

Now I want to add automatically more names do my dependent dropdown list.

- If E8 = "Tool" then copy the name that is in cell E6 to last row of column "L"
- If E8 = "Equipment" then copy the name that is in cell E6 to last row of column "K"
- Same with if E8 = "Car"

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub Move()
Dim row, column As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet

'Determine Column
Select Case ws.Cells(8, 5).Value

    Case "Equipment"
        column = 11
    Case "Tool"
        column = 12
    Case "Car"
        column = 13

End Select

If column = 0 Then
    Exit Sub
End If

'Determine row
row = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, column).End(xlUp).row + 1

'Put value in cell
ws.Cells(row, column).Value = ws.Cells(6, 5).Value

End Sub
```

Comment: Peter, a BIG THANK YOU! It works perfectly! Couldnt find the answers anywhere. Thank you again :D

Comment: I changed the template. I added a new worksheet that contains the range of the dependent dropdown list. This means that the table from the columns K to M are in this new sheet. How can I adapt this change to the code given by Peter? Let's assume the table in the new worksheet is in the same columns (K to M). Thank you all